# Impossible to nameref Appendix Sections

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, titlesec, appendices, nameref

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}

Some text.

As stated in Appendix Chapter ``\nameref{appendix:chapter1}'', there is an Appendix Section named ``\nameref{appendix:section1}''.

\begin{appendices}

\chapter*{Some appendix chapter}
\label{appendix:chapter1}

Some appendix text. A Section will follow.

\section*{A section inside appendix chapter}
\label{appendix:section1}

Some appendix section text.

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The second reference, `\nameref{appendix:section1}`, is not printed in the output. If I don't use the package `titlesec`, it works instead.

I need `titlesec` to have more depth in the document structure: to be able to use a `paragraph` with its own title, nested inside a `subsubsection`.

[This solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196021/74786) doesn't work in my case.

Either of these two options is OK for me:

1. Is it possible to still `nameref` an Appendix Section in a document using `titlesec`? If yes, how?
2. Is it possible to create `\paragraph*{some title}` without `titlesec`, thus being able to `nameref` an Appendix Section? If yes, how?

---

[This solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123667/74786) is not suitable, because it has the side-effect of numerating `\section*{Introduction}` despite the `*`.

[image]

Comment: You can find the solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123667/231952

Comment: you don't need titlesec to be able to use \paragraph.

Comment: @Ivan Thanks, it works as regards the `nameref`, but it numerates the `\section*{Introduction}`, despite the star. So, it doesn't fit to my case.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I edited the question: this would be another suitable solution for me. How to avoid the use of `titlesec` while still having paragraphs with their own title?